# Two Identical queries one with SQL parameter and other with hard code string value providing different result set

Tags: where-clause, varchar, prepared-statement, varcharmax

Two identical Queries are returning different results in where clause. The first query is with **SQL parameter variable** and the second query with a **string value** as mentioned below. The result of both queries should be the same as both have the same values but it is not happening. what could be the reason for that?

```
Declare @messageID AS INT=720987
Declare @replyfileType AS Varchar='Audio'

select VoiceMessageReply from MDBDetails where MessageID = @messageID and FileType=@replyfileType

select VoiceMessageReply from MDBDetails where MessageID = @messageID and FileType='Audio'
```

Result is as :-
[Query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22kVW.png)

Comment: And today we learn why we should always specify a length with `varchar`. The default length is **1**.

Comment: Specify the varchar size

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration:

```
Declare @replyfileType AS Varchar = 'Audio';
```

Is declaring a one character string, so it is equivalent to:

```
Declare @replyfileType AS Varchar(1) = 'A';
```

*Always* include the length when using strings in SQL Server!

```
Declare @replyfileType AS Varchar(255) = 'Audio';
```

I should note that if you printed out `@replyfileType` the error would be obvious.